# What do WiFi power saving modes (energy saving modes) on computers (esp laptops) really mean?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, power, wifi-configuration, energy-saving

If you dive into power saving (energy saving) mode on most computers (and nearly all laptops), you'll see a variety of levels at which you can specify the amount of power savings for wireless adapters (WiFi).  These can often be found under "Wireless Adapter Settings".

Choices using generic terminology are typically provided, such as:

- Maximum Performance
- Low Power Savings
- Medium Power Savings
- Maximum Power Savings

Going beyond these generic terms, what are the specific differences between each of these power savings modes?

Comment: [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005879/wireless/legacy-intel-wireless-products.html) has a great description

Comment: And [Change Power Saving Mode of Wireless Adapters in Windows 10 | Tutorials](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/82794-change-power-saving-mode-wireless-adapters-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Thank you Ramhound and David.  I'll write back if I have any questions.